# What should I do if the 2nd malloc failed in the same constructor

Tags: c++, malloc, raii

**Note that** the basis of the question is to use two `malloc()`s...while suggesting not using `malloc()` at all is perfectly valid and leads to better design, this is not the point of the question. Perhaps you can think that my client is a psychopath and I am paid to have two `malloc()`s.

===== Here comes the question itself =====

Say I am stuck with the following class and cannot switch to features such as `vector<int>`, `unique_ptr<int>`, etc, while not "modern", it should still work without leaking any memory, whether or not `malloc()` succeeds:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        int *ptr;
    public:
        Foo () {
            this->ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR_SIZE);
            if (this->ptr == NULL) {
                std::bad_alloc exception;
                throw exception;
            }
        }
        ~Foo () {
            free(this->ptr);
        }

};
```

The question appears if I need to `malloc()` twice within the same constructor:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        int *ptr0;
        int *ptr1;
    public:
        Foo () {
            this->ptr0 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR_SIZE_0);
            if (this->ptr0 == NULL) {
                std::bad_alloc exception;
                throw exception;
            }
            this->ptr1= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR_SIZE_1);
            if (this->ptr1== NULL) {
                free(this->ptr0); // QUESTION: Is this needed and does it follow the best practice?
                std::bad_alloc exception;
                throw exception;
            }
        }
        ~Foo () {
            free(this->ptr0);
            free(this->ptr1);
        }

};
```

I am aware that it could be more advisable in the 2nd case that we create two classes which wrap one pointer each, so the principle of RAII can be thoroughly followed and the above kind of "C-style" `free()` in constructor is not needed.

The question is, say, for whatever reason, I must have two `malloc()`s in the constructor, is my design good enough (i.e., not leaking memory and not too verbose)?

Comment: I would first write a smart pointer, something akin to unique_ptr that does the allocation. 
Then if the second allocation fails the destructor of the first allocated pointer should be called. (either use try catch block or a scope guard in the constructor)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` works perfectly fine with `malloc` (or any other resource-allocating function), you just need to supply a custom deleter.

Comment: "assuming the first malloc fails, ptr1 will be uninitialized" C functions don't work this way. If `malloc` fails, it returns a null pointer.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, but when the first exception triggers, the second malloc won't be called at all, leaving `ptr1` uninitialized.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium This is OK.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I dont get your 1st comment. Say 1st malloc failed, ptr0's value is NULL and ptr1 is uninitialized. But I think this is fine as an exception is thrown and both pointers, as variables, go out of scope, no memory is leaked and their 8 bytes memory get reclaimed by OS. As long as we dont dereference ptr1, I think being uninitialized should be fine.

Comment: @JaMiT I changed the term from "functions" to "features".

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Yeah, my bad. I made the mistake of believing that the destructor would be called upon unwinding, only to be notified that it won't be, because construction never completed.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `unique_ptr` to help with memory management?

Comment: Are you aware that copying your class will cause a double-free?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili True, this class needs the rule of three/five: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: What the heck is `malloc` doing in a C++ program in the first place? And why "can't" you use the language as it's supposed to be used (containers, smart pointers and all)? Please don't tell me this is **another** case of "C++ taught the worst way possible"...

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I believe the above sample wont compile as copy constructor cant be implicitly defined by compiler. So whether or not there will be double free depends on the definition of copy constructor, which is not involved in this question...

Comment: @DevSolar this is about what C++ standard allows user to do, in "edge cases" if you wish.

Comment: @DevSolar some of us still need to interface with other languages.

Comment: @n.m. One, that would not necessitate `malloc` in a constructor in any way I could see. And two, that does not justify sending beginners through C hell and then expecting them to unlearn all those bad habits once (if?) they get to actually use C++. Java has to interface with other languages as well; you don't make Java beginners reimplement standard containers with one hand on their back and using `malloc`, either.

Comment: @DevSolar oh I am from hell then . I think being as close to bare metal as C sets C++ apart ...otherwise why don't people just use java...(does java have a stable ABI? Idk..)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind C is a solid programming language, I don't dispute that. It's just that C++ is  a very much **different** language, and what's good practice in C is often terrible practice in C++. It's one thing to have students come from a C course to a C++ course. But if you are learning C++ **do learn** idiomatic C++, and don't lazily expand your C code with a bit of syntactic sugar while essentially still writing the same low-level stuff as before. It hurts readability, maintainability, and effectiveness of your code. And C++ can be just as effective as C, sometimes even more so.

Comment: @DevSolar OP did not ask what kind of memory management is best to use. Evidently OP knows that, so no need to reiterate. OP specifically asked what to do when for some reason or another `malloc` must be used. Who am I to judge?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a RAII-enabled version.

```
struct Free
{
   void operator()(void* p) const { std::free(p); }
};

template <typename T, typename Deleter = Free>
std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> raii_malloc()
{
   T* obj = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(sizeof(T)));
   if (obj == nullptr) throw std::bad_alloc();
   return std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>(obj);
}

template <typename T, typename Deleter = Free>
std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter> raii_malloc_array(size_t size)
{
   T* obj = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(sizeof(T) * size));
   if (obj == nullptr) throw std::bad_alloc();
   return std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>(obj);
}

template <typename T>
using fptr = std::unique_ptr<T, Free>;
```

Now your class looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
      fptr<int[]> ptr0;
      fptr<int[]> ptr1;
   public:
      Foo() : ptr0{raii_malloc_array<int>(ARR_SIZE_0)},
              ptr1{raii_malloc_array<int>(ARR_SIZE_1)}
      {}
      // no destructor needed
};
```

Note that this version is non-copyable. If you need copying, add a custom copy constructor and/or assignment operator (still no destructor needed).

You can use this with C objects that contain internal pointers or other resources that need to be freed, you just need to supply a different deleter instead of `Free`.

If `unique_ptr` is not available, it is extremely easy to roll your own simplified version.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` to help manage memory.
2. Don't use `malloc` unless you must.
3. Make sure your class is either safe to copy/move, or not copyable/movable (i.e., deleted constructor, `operator=`).
4. Think about how likely you are to handle an out-of-memory case anyway (are you going to open a file and log it while you're out of system memory?), and perhaps just terminate if the allocation fails.

Comment: OP said he cannot use std::vector. It looks like he is stuck on a very old version of C++

Comment: @PepijnKramer `std::vector` has always been a part of the language, it's not a new addition.

Comment: No it hasn't always been part of C++ (It was not in 1995 when I started using C++). And yes there are still (legacy) compilers out there that do not support it. 
I regret that but it is true ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer if OP needs help with a pre-standardization compiler, it's likely that we can't help at all unless he specifies which version of which compiler he's using.

Comment: That is also true

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes that is the point, I meant "what if" I have to avoid all the "modern" staff like `vector<int>`, `unique_ptr<int>`, etc...

Comment: @D.J.Elkind `vector` is not modern by any means (as old as the standard language itself). If `vector` is too new for your application, you need to tell us exactly what we're working with, otherwise we can't reason about it at all.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili okay let me drop the term, i meant:  "what if" I have to avoid all staff like `vector<int>`, `unique_ptr<int>`, etc...

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Assuming it's regular C++ but you don't have access to a standard library (e.g., on an  embedded system or something like that), you should probably write your own minimal class to implement something like `unique_ptr`, otherwise you'll end up with messy code with lots of `goto`s and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple way to avoid the issue would be to allocate the necessary memory for your member variables in one go.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo()
        {
            ptr0 = new int[ARR_SIZE0 + ARR_SIZE1];
            ptr1 = ptr0 + ARR_SIZE0;
        }

        ~Foo()
        {
            delete ptr0[];
        }

        // PLEASE insert the rest of the
        // necessary constructors
        // and assignment operators...

    private:
        int * ptr0;
        int * ptr1;
};
```

Using `new` instead of `malloc` here because, if you **have** to do manual allocations, at least do them using the C++ construct.

Comment: But you should really, really ask your instructor to allow you actually using C++, not "C with classes". Not having to do this manual allocation rigamarole is basically the whole point of *using* C++. There should be no reason to have manual memory allocation, owning pointers, or even C arrays in C++ source that is not hieroglyphics-ancient.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated question makes it clearer what the question is about. I feel my first answer still holds value, but this one goes in another direction entirely, which is why I wrote it as a separate answer.

It boils down to:

> If I am about to throw an exception from a constructor, do I have to actively release resources previously allocated manually in that constructor?

**Yes, you do**, for any resources that you would likewise have to `free` / `close` / `disconnect` / ... in the destructor.

If a constructor fails (i.e., throws), the object **is not constructed**. It is, therefore, not **destructed** either -- its destructor will never be called. You would lose access to `ptr0` and `ptr1`. Your exception might be caught, the program might continue -- but you would have leaked the memory.

So, again, **yes**, please **do** release any resource you would release in the destructor that you already allocated in the constructor before throwing the exception.

---

All the other comments and remarks also hold true, though. You should strive not to mix C constructs and C++ constructs. Writing idiomatic C++ instead of what is disparagingly called "C with classes" will result in better readable, more stable and likely more efficient code.

Comment: your "boils down to" part is largely correct, this is sort of what I want to ask. However, I am **not** asking "if", but asking "how"--I am already aware that destructor won't be called, but I am a bit concerned if my own design can properly handle **all** cases well (in the sense that it is 100% RAII-complaint)--given the strict limit that I have to have two `malloc()`s in it. You can think like I am paid to add two `malloc()` to constructor for whatever reason.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind As many operating systems are overcommiting memory, which ends in e.g. `malloc` returning non-zero and the application being terminated for out-of-memory anyway if you *access* that memory, there is no such thing as "all cases". Your questioning is oddly specific...

Comment: okay then, sorry for asking a wrong question. It is my fault.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind That is not what I wanted to say. I don't understand what it is that remains unanswered for you. If you use two malloc, and the second fails, you'd need to free the first before throwing. But you are very likely looking at a non-recoverable error anyway.